# Encrypting data within SQLite database in Java - How to store key?

Tags: encryption, java, databases

So, a bit of context before I start may be handy.
I am developing a Java desktop application which will use an SQLite database to store/process data. The application will utilize authentication to access the program for editing data, adding/deleting data, etc. But I don't want an attacker to be able to pull the laptop's hard drive and access the data without first authenticating to Windows.

My question is, if I were to encrypt certain data before inserting into the SQLite database with say...AES256, is it possible to decrypt the data without the user having to insert a password AND without hardcoding the password in the application? I really think the overhead of the user having to remember 2 passwords (one for application authentication and one for database encryption/decryption) is infeasable because if they forget the encryption/decryption password, their data is gone..

Have any of you come across any solutions that you can share or suggest some ideas that may be of help?

Comment: Why do you want to encrypt the data in the database? The only reason I see to do that is if you want to protect the user data against the developers of the application (so yourself).

Comment: So, the reason for encrypting the database is to prevent access to the database from "the side" so, when the database file is not in use by the application, I dont want the ability that a hacker could open and read the file in PHP MyAdmin for example.

Comment: If the attacker can access your database, it probably means that your server is compromised. This then means that nothing on your server is safe. If you are expecting your server to be compromised, the only solution you have left is to encrypt/decrypt everything on the client side, like LastPass is doing for example. But really, most applications out there expect that the server is not compromised...

Comment: This solution is for a local DB, on a personal laptop. So I am working back from a physical security breach and the possibility that a user has not utilized windows authentication to access their profile or that their windows credentials are also compromised. The possibility is that access to the DB file is a likelihood. This is the reason I am investigating this, so as to ensure the confidentiality of the data in a worst case scenario.

Comment: "But really, most applications out there expect that the server is not compromised" I would counter that all sane applications expect that the server may inevitably be compromised.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When the user do the first login your software will ask for a new password.
At this time the DB should be empty.

Now you have a **UserPassword** and an empty DB.
So the software generate a new random **DBdataKey** that will be used to encrypt/decrypt the DB contents. To encrypt/decrypt use one of the many known algorithms, like AES or similar one.

Now you create 2 random salt string: **PasswordSalt** and **DBdataKeySalt**.
Store **PasswordSalt** and **DBdataKeySalt** in the DB as a clear text.

Use a hash function like pbkdf2 (or something like SHA2 or better) with **UserPassword** and **DBdataKeySalt** to obtain a **DBdataKeyEncryptionKey**

Now:
**DBdataKey** is the key you use to encrypt/decrypt the DB contents
**DBdataKeyEncryptionKey** is the key you use to encrypt/decrypt the **DBdataKey**

Use a hash function like pbkdf2 (or something like SHA2 or better) with **UserPassword** and **PasswordSalt** to create **HashedSaltedUserPassword**, a salted-hashed version of the **UserPassword**, then use **DBdataKey** to encrypt **HasedSaltedUserPassword** before storing it in the DB.

From now on you can use **DBdataKey** to encrypt/decrypt the data to/from the DB.

Now, when the user opens the application, you ask him for the password, then use the inputed password with **DBdataKeySalt** (which is stored in cleartext) to regenerate the **DBdataKeyEncryptionKey**, and then use the obtained **DBdataKeyEncryptionKey** to decrypt the **DBdataKey** , and so you can use the decrypted **DBdataKey** to read the DB.

Now use the **DBdataKey** to decrypt the **HashedSaltedUserPassword** and compare it with the one you regenerated using the inputed password and the **PasswordSalt** (which is stored in cleartext) just to double-check that the login information is correct.

If the user inputs the wrong password, when you use the **DBdataKeyEncryptionKey** to decrypt the **DBdataKey** the decrypt function will give you a different value (garbage). Using that (wrong) value to decrypt the **HashedSaltedUserPassword** will result in more garbage values, which won't match the hash.

When the user changes the **UserPassword**  then you only need to decrypt the **DBdataKey**  with the old password and re-encrypt it with the new password, but the **DBdataKey** won't change, so you won't need to re-encrypt the db contents when the user changes its password.

**Reference:** I haven't invented anything, this is just a mix of two well known techniques:

- How user-login & [password salting/hashing](https://crackstation.net/hashing-security.htm) is done
- How on-the-fly disk encryption can be implemented (applied to DB encryption/decryption)

Comment: Even better: you also encrypt the “salted hash” (use something like pbkdf2) with the "DB key" so even bruteforcing the user password will be harder (if the user password is wrong, you will be decrypting with the wrong DB key, and the hash won't match). Plus replace all mentions of *encrypt with the user password* with *a hash/hmac of the user password*

Comment: @Ángel thanks, I rewrote the answer to include your suggestion

Comment: @Max and Ángel, Thank you very much! Extremely in-depth and well thought out solution, I really appreciate your help!

Comment: Some functionality is lost, likr in `select * from table where col like '%string%'`, isn't it?